# Angularjs print value in localstorage

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs how to print name in **localstorage**

i try this `console.log($scope.storageData.name);` //output is Undifiend

```
var user = angular.toJson(response.data.user);
localStorage.setItem('user', user);
$rootScope.authenticated = true;
$scope.storageData = localStorage.getItem("user");
console.log($scope.storageData);
console.log($scope.storageData.name);
```

output

```
{"id":20,"name":"test","email":"test@gmail.com","roles":"","created_at":"2018-02-27 10:07:53","updated_at":"2018-03-02 06:51:26"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse it to an **`object`** before accessing **`name`**

```
$scope.storageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it to an object first. Your this line here:

```
$scope.storageData = localStorage.getItem( "user" );
```

Should be changed with this:

```
$scope.storageData = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( "user" ) );
```